# jQuery detect the length of a string

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to highlight a searched terms which is working well. The problem is that I would like to avoid having 1 or 2 character words or "the" and 'and.'

if I use

```
var term = $('#q').val().split(/\s+/);
     if(term.length < 3){
    $('p').highlight(term);
     }
```

it will take the input value as a whole string, so it has more then 3 letters.

so I guess I need to use

```
if(term:contains('and')){}
```

but the trick is how will I un-highlight that?

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eayan/14/)

Comment: the higlihgt function is pulled from https://raw.github.com/bartaz/sandbox.js/master/jquery.highlight.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You checked the length of the string `array` and not actually the length of each `string`, this should work:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var term = $('#q').val().split(/\s+/);
    for(var i=0;i<term.length;i++)
    { 
       if(term[i].length > 3)
        $('p').highlight(term[i]);      
    }          
 });
```

FIDDLE
http://jsfiddle.net/eayan/16/

**UPDATE**:
To allow terms set up one array of allowed words i.e:

```
var allowed = ["xp","try"];
```

change the if to:

```
if(term[i].length > 3 || $.inArray(term[i],allowed) >= 0)
```

for case insensitive search you gotta make some tunes

[Fiddle - allowed words](http://jsfiddle.net/eayan/23/)

Comment: is there a way to exclude some words that I need to highlight but have less letters. ie XP?

Comment: I see some problem because "by" is also highlighted and it shouldn't be because is less then 3 letters

Comment: sorry, the result of inArray must be >= so means it was found

Answer (score 1):

You can replace remove the words you don't want:

```
var term = $("#q").val();

var unwantedWords = ['the', 'and', 'this', 'that', 'a', 'an'];

// remove unwanted words 
for (var i = 0; i < unwantedWords.length; i++) {
    term = term.replace(new RegExp("\\s+" + unwantedWords[i]), "");
}

term = term.split(/\s+/);

$('p').highlight(term);
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eayan/20/)

Comment: excelent, thanks a lot. I wish if I could give two good answers!

Comment: one more question though. How would I do opposite. Now I hide the words smaller then 3 letters but if I need some words that have only 2 letters?

Comment: @SamotnyPocitac See my updated solution. You can create an array of unwanted words, and remove each of them. This makes is a bit more extensible; if you uncover additional words you don't want, you can just add them to the array. It also means that it isn't dependent on the length of the word, but on the word itself (e.g. article adjetives, etc.);

Comment: that doesn't seem to work, you can even see in your demo that and is highlighted

Comment: @SamotnyPocitac There was a syntax error. JSHint ftw. Updated